# Defining a member function inside the class instead of outside in C++?

Tags: c++, function, inline, header-files

By writing the definition of a member function inside the class in the header file as follows, I was told that compiler treats this as an inline function - hence , anywhere it encounters this function being called in the program , it enters the complete body of the function every time instead of jumping to the one location where the function resides in memory. Is this true?

```
class myClass
{
    public:
       void Fun1()
       {
         //implemented here
       }
}
```

Comment: You seem to be confused about what `inline` means and how it relates to "inlining". The `inline` keyword is first and foremost an aspect of the one-definition-rule. Code generation is a secondary issue.

Answer (score 2):

> I was told that compiler treats this as an inline function

Correct. That means that it's allowed to be defined in more than one translation unit, which is necessary if you want to define it in a header and include that header more than once in your program.

> Hence , anywhere it encounters this function being called in the program , it enters the complete body of the function every time instead of jumping to the one location where the function resides in memory

No, that's not what `inline` means in the context of a function definition. That's the optimisation of function call inlining, which the compiler can apply to any call if it thinks it will improve the code.

The two concepts are loosely related: compilers which process a single translation unit at a time will only be able to apply the optimisation to functions defined in the current unit, so they'll need to have multiple definitions to be able to optimise them in more than one unit.

Comment: Don't we include a header guard in the header files to stop it being included in the code more than once? In that case, what is the difference between defining the function outside or inside the header file. Won't the compiler just jump to where the function resides in memory all the time?

Comment: @Engineer999: The header guard prevents multiple inclusions within a single translation unit. It doesn't prevent including it from more than one translation unit; doing that will give an error if the function isn't inline.

Comment: If the function implementations are included in the header file but outside the class by using the scope operator ::, Is this different?

Comment: @Engineer999: Yes. If it's inside the class, then it's implicitly inline. Outside the class, you'll have to mark it `inline`.

Comment: Sorry to keep on and on, but what is the difference then if any to implementing the function in the header file (but outside the class) or implementing it in a separate .cpp file?

Comment: @Engineer999: If it's defined in a header, then it can be defined in multiple translation units, by including the header in each. For some compilers, that's necessary if you want it to be able to inline the function calls; without "whole program optimsation", the function definition must be available in the current translation unit in order to inline it. If it's only defined in a single source file, then it might not be possible to inline calls to it from other translation units.

Answer (score 1):

If your question is whether this is equivalent to:

```
class myClass
{
public:
   void Fun1();
};

inline void myClass::Fun1()
{
     //implemented here
}
```

the answer is: YES.

If your question is whether the function will be physically expanded inline, the answer is: UNDEFINED. Depends on compiler's optimization flags and rules how it works.

The meaning of "inlining" in C++ is: if the compiler emits this function as out-of-line (either by not expanding at all or as alternative), it undergoes weak (vague) linkage (two such functions in two different object files linked together results in taking the first one as a good deal).

That's in contrast to normal external function, which undergo strong linkage (two such functions in two different object files linked together results in linker error).

Answer (score 0):

If you define a function within a class definition, it is by default inline ( without needing to specify 'inline')

The compiler replaces all instances of an inline function call with the actual code.

Note: the compiler may ignore the 'inline' qualifier of a function if it is more than one line. You will also need to recompile all componnents (the ones which utilize that function) so that compiler can replace the code block with the new code.

Answer (score 0):

You are right that the function with definition in the header file is implicitly "inline". But the `inline` keyword is just a hint to the compiler. Depending on its implementation, on the function contents and on the optimization flags, the compiler may decide to inline a function or not.